# How to make buyer of my NFT pay the gas fee for minting?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas, erc-721, nft

I want to set up a dApp where i sell create and sell my own NFT's. Is it possible to put the gas fee's onto the buyer so they pay for all the gas? And how would i do that if so?

Comment: Did someone already find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In NFT creation and minting; the process is for the NFT owner to create the token (and mint the required quantity) and let the transfer of nft to buyers.
The process lets the owner of the nft bare the gas for creation and transfer(or mint).
Rather, the mint function can be called directly by the user who intends to buy, paying the gas and appropriate amount to buy the nft.

Comment: For someone to pay fees, this someone must send the transaction itself.

Comment: So how would the user who intends to buy be able to transfer the token to themselves if they aren't the owner? (ie if they were already the owner it wouldn't need to be transferred right?)

I can get the end user to call the mint function but then do i need to still call the transfer function myself?

Comment: @SafeerHayat make it so the mint function mints the NFT to the end user

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here. 1st is to mint the nft yourself, pay the gas fee and then add it to the price. 2nd is to mint the NFT upon purchase (how you would do it depends on how you set up your dApp) so the buyer pays the fee